# How is (¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) not Satisfiable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

`(¬p ∨ ¬q ∨ r) ∧ (¬p ∨ q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ ¬q ∨ ¬s) ∧ (¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s) ∧ (p ∨ q ∨ ¬r) ∧ (p ∨ ¬r ∨ ¬s)`

I'm studying The book "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications" Page 36 Exercise 62

The book says it is NOT satisfiable, I say if you set `p`, `s` and `r` to `False`, Then it is satisfiable, I'm I right ? or I need to re-read the entire chapter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you: The expression *is* satisfiable.  Specifically, any of the following combinations of $(p, q, r, s)$ will work:

- (False, False, False, False)
- (False, False, False, True)
- (False, True, False, False)
- (False, True, True, False)
- (True, False, False, False)
- (True, False, True, False)
- (True, True, True, False)

Maybe they made a typo, or meant to ask if there's a *unique* solution.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Each of the $6$ conjuncts prohibits only $2$ of the $16$ possible truth assignments, so several truth assignments must remain unprohibited.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand

Comment: @Zeko  There are 16 possible truth-assignments (or, if you're more comfortable thinking about this in terms of truth-tables: there are $16$ possible rows in the truth-table).  Now, a term like $(\neg p \lor \neg q \lor r)$ would be false if and only if $p$ is True, $q$ is True, and $r$ is False, while $s$ can have either truth-value. So, it is False in 2 of those 16 truth-assignments (or again, in terms of truth-tables: the term would be False in $2$ of those $16$ rows).  Also note that all terms look like this, and as such make the statement False in exactly $2$ rows. .. (continued)

Comment: So, with $6$ terms, each ruling out exactly $2$ possibilities, together they can rule out at most $12$ rows, so we know that there are at least $4$ rows in the table where the whole sentence is True. ... And so yes, you must be right that the sentence is satisfiable. This is what @AndreasBlass meant.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you've written here is satisfiable. Punching it into a [truth table generator](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/) yields many different satisfying assignments, of which setting $p$, $q$, $r$, and $s$ to false is one option.

Perhaps this is a typographical error in the book, or perhaps what you have above isn't an exact copy?